# How can I pass parameter from scala.html to javascript in play framework?

Tags: javascript, scala

```
@(message: String)(exchangelist: java.util.ArrayList[String])(implicit session: play.mvc.Http.Session)
@main(title = message)(session) {
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
  <script>
     startup(exchangelist);
  <script>
</body>
```

Code like this, how can I pass parameter "exchangelist" to Js function "startup()"? This method don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying the meta tag:

```html
    <html>
        <head>
            <!-- <meta name="exchangelist" content='@{exchangelist.mkstring(",")}'> -->
            <meta name="exchangelist" content='yellow,black,green'>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        </head>

        <script>
            function startup(list) {
                alert("startup called with " + list);
            }

            var el = $('meta[name=exchangelist]').attr("content").split(",");
            startup(el);
        </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: The snippet wasn't complete and thus not runnable. I edited it so you can run it using the run button. You'll also have to replace the line with the meta tag with the commented one above to actually render the scala list's content.